# Can I use xml properties file instead of application.properties in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: xml, properties, spring-boot

In our **Spring Boot** application we use **application.properties**, but there's a requirement from the Ops team to use XML based properties file. The format is simple. If **apllication.properties** looks like:

```
com.mail.host=mail_host
db.connection.port=1521
```

the corresponding xml should be:

```
<XML>
    <com>
        <mail>
            <host>
                mail_host
            </host>
        </mail>
    </com>
    <db>
        <connection>
            <port>
                1521
            </port>
        </connection>
    </db>
</XML>
```

We implemented that, but **Spring Boot** is still looking for the **application.properties** in order to get its specific properties. This is somewhat inconvenient. We want to have all the properties in one place, i.e. - the XML file.

What's the best way of overriding the default behavior of **Spring Boot**, to make it look for the properties in the XML file? (Of course, it will need some custom code, because **Spring Boot** understands simple property format (like **key=value**) and the YAML format, but no XML.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to write our own XML parser. We already have that. The question is how to make Spring Boot read the specific properties from the XML file, because SB tries to read them automatically from the application.properties when the app starts and we can't make it use our custom XML parser.

Appeared to be easier than I thought. When the app starts, our code invokes a static initializer method that reads the props from the XML file using our custom parser. It sets the Spring Boot specific properties as system ones, by calling:

```
System.setProperty(...)
```

Later on, the Spring Boot is able to get these prop values, just as if they are given in the application.properties.

Answer (score 8):

Spring Boot not only reads properties from files with extensions .properties & .yaml but also from .xml. Rather than application.properties just provide application.xml on your resource folder in following format:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <comment>Application properties in XML format</comment>
    <entry key="com.mail.host">mail_host</entry>
    <entry key="db.connection.port">1521</entry>
</properties>
```

On your class file you can simply set values like the way we do with any properties or yaml files i.e. `@Value("${com.mail.host}")` will set respective value on whatever instance variable it will annotate to.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that, but it's not exactly what we need. Like I mentioned above, we have a specific XML format ...

Comment: Probably then you need to write your own xml parser class for the xml which will read the xml at app startup and then add it to the property source via environment handle (like @tombola82 point of adding).

Comment: I tried to find xml import in spring boot manual, but it looks like not mentioned there https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must load properties from a custom xml source then this article may be helpful:

https://coderwall.com/p/mm5ihw/how-to-add-custom-property-source-to-spring-s-environment

It provides an example of loading custom properties via Java config in Spring 3 from some networked source, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the code to read from your Ops team's XML format into your SpringBoot app.